# Need assistance on setting up an alphabetical list from a file of multiple 7 char lines

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


struct dictionary {
    char *data;
    struct dictionary *nextPtr;

};

typedef struct dictionary Dictionary;
typedef Dictionary* DictionaryPtr; 

// Prototypes
void printList(DictionaryPtr currentPtr);
void insert(DictionaryPtr *sPtr, char *value);
int isEmpty(DictionaryPtr sPtr);


void insert(DictionaryPtr *sPtr, char *value){

    DictionaryPtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Dictionary));



    if(newPtr != NULL){
        newPtr->data = value;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        DictionaryPtr previousPtr = NULL;
        DictionaryPtr currentPtr = *sPtr;


        while(currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data){
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if(previousPtr == NULL){
            newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
            *sPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else{
            previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("%s not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
    }
}


int isEmpty(DictionaryPtr sPtr){
    return sPtr == NULL;
}

void printList(DictionaryPtr currentPtr){
    //if empty
    if(isEmpty(currentPtr)){
        printf("List is empty.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The list is:");

        while(currentPtr != NULL){
            printf("%s --> ", currentPtr->data);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->rightPtr;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}
int main(void){

    FILE *fp = fopen("P4WORDS.TXT", "r"); 
        if (fp == NULL){
            printf("Dictionary file not included in file structure");
            exit(0);
        }
    
    fseek()
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
        int bytes = ftell(fp); 
        int count = bytes / 8; 
    
        DictionaryPtr startPtr = NULL;
        char word[8];
        int byteCount = 0;
    
    
        while (byteCount < bytes){
            fseek(fp, byteCount, SEEK_SET); 
            if(fgets(word, 8, fp) != NULL){ 
                    insert(&startPtr, word);
                    printList(startPtr);
            }
            //rewind(fp);
            byteCount = byteCount + 8;
        }
    
        printList(startPtr);
        return 0;
}
```

I currently have this as of now, and what seems to happen is it ends up printing the last word from the file multiple times into the list. I tested and made sure data is picked up, but it seems to overwrite itself each time it iterates through. I think there is some error in the insert() or setup of my dictionary struct... I just can't seem to pinpoint it. Would anyone have a pointer on how I can properly store and print out the list?

The file consists of...

```
Abandon
Abating
Abdomen
Abetted
Abetter
Abettor
Abiding
Abigail
Ability
Abjured
Abolish
Aborted
Abounds
Abraham
Abreast
Abridge
Absalom
Abscess
Abscond
Absence
Absolve
Absorbs
Abstain
Abusing
Abusive
Abysmal
Academy
Acceded
Accents
Accepts
Acclaim
Accords
Account
Accrued
Accrues
Accusal
Accused
Accuser
Accuses
Accusor
Acetate
Acetone
Achaean
Achieve
Acidity
Acolyte
Acquire
Acreage
Acrobat
Acronym
Acrylic
Actions
Actives
Actress
Actuary
Actuate
Acutely
Adagios
Adamant
Adapted
Adapter
Adaptor
Addenda
Addicts
Addison
Addling
Address
Adeline
Adenoma
Adeptly
Adhered
Adheres
Adjoins
Adjourn
Adjudge
Adjunct
Adjusts
Admiral
Admired
Admirer
Admires
Admixed
Adopted
Adoring
Adorned
Adrenal
Adsorbs
Adulate
Advance
Adverbs
Adverse
Advised
Adviser
Advises
```

Comment: TLDR --- looks like you're using the same memory over and over for different words. Maybe you need to `malloc()` and `strcpy()` (`strdup()` if your system has it and you don't mind losing a bit of portability)? ... don't forgte to free resources once you're done with them.

Comment: `newPtr->data = value;` The function gets called with the same `word` variable every time. Make a copy with `strdup`. Don't forget to `free` when no longer needed.

Comment: the posted code does not compile! 1) struct dictionary does not contain a field: `nextptr`  2) regarding: `fseek()` causes error of too few arguments  3) this statement: `typedef struct dictionary Dictionary;dictionary` contains a 'stray' trailing: `dictionary`  4) the posted code causes the compiler to also output several warnings.

Comment: OT: regarding: `else{
        printf("%s not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
    }`  it is best to inform the user of an error via outputting to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Also, best to output to `stderr` the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest `perror( "malloc failed" );`

Comment: OT: regarding; `while(currentPtr != NULL){
            printf("%s --> ", currentPtr->data);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->rightPtr;
        }`  this 'could' result in a line on your terminal that is hundreds of characters long. suggest: `printf("%s -->\n ", currentPtr->data);`  With the addition of the '\n', the result will be one entry per line.

Comment: Please do not replace the posted code as that makes the current  comments nonsense.   Rather, ADD an EDIT section with the corrected code.

Comment: regarding: `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
        int bytes = ftell(fp);` `ftell()` can fail AND returns a `long int`, not an `int`.  `ftell()` can fail and returns 0 upon success.

Comment: regarding; `if(fgets(word, 8, fp) != NULL){`  Since the input file is a text file, each line would be terminated via a '\n'.  The function: `fgets()` will include that '\n' in the input buffer.  Therefore, should eliminate the '\n' via: `word[ strcspn( word, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `while (byteCount < bytes){
            fseek(fp, byteCount, SEEK_SET); 
            if(fgets(word, 8, fp) != NULL){ 
                    insert(&startPtr, word);
                    printList(startPtr);
            }
            //rewind(fp);
            byteCount = byteCount + 8;
        }` When `fgets()` fails, (I.E. returns NULL) then should have a `break;` statement to exit the `while()` loop